# Palabra que define a un ignorante que no sabe que es ignorante

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Busco una palabra que define a un ignorante pero que no sabe que es ignorante.

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre igno-ignorate. Pero no me creo que el ser humano no tenga una palabra que defina esto.

Comment: Lo llamaría "doblemente ignorante". No hay peor ignorante que aquel que no reconoce su ignorancia.

Comment: No creo que haya una palabra para éste estado de ánimo. Todas ellas conllevan juzgar a la persona.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar pido disculpas por si alguien se siente algo ofendido, no es la intención, pues es una expresión vulgar, aunque bastante utilizada al menos en España, así **una palabra que define a un ignorante que no sabe que es ignorante**, es "gilipollas". Estamos hablando de **un tonto, idiota o ignorante que no sabe que lo es**, esta es la clave de la cuestión y por tal en el ámbito popular, recibe ese calificativo por parte de los demás.

Existen otras palabras, como sinónimos que se solapan y que hacen referencia a "ignorante", *como grosero, rudo, zafio, rústico*... pero no a la segunda parte, es decir, aquella en la que "no sabe que es un ignorante". Así queda "gili", desde mi opinión, como forma más suavizada para indicar a ese "tipo de personas que siendo ignorantes no lo saben".

---

> **Gilipollas.** ‘Tonto o idiota’:
>
> «Nuestro Raúl se ha convertido en un auténtico gilipollas» (Mendizábal Cumpleaños [Esp. 1992]).
>
> Esta palabra vulgar, usada solo en España, así como otras voces de la misma
> familia, como **gilí** y **gilipollez**, y el sustituto eufemístico
> **gilipuertas**, se escriben siempre con g-.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/gilipollas

---

> **Gilipollas** Como adjetivo.
>
> 1 En el sentido de Simple
>
> Ejemplo: ¡Jacinta! Anda y se ríe el muy simple.
>
> Simple sustantivo masculino
>
> Tonto sustantivo masculino, adjetivo masculino
>
> Idiota
>
> Torpe
>
> Imbécil
>
> Estúpido adjetivo masculino
>
> Estúpido adjetivo masculino
>
> Bobo sustantivo masculino, adjetivo masculino
>
> **Necio** adjetivo masculino
>
> Asno sustantivo masculino, masculino, adjetivo masculino
>
> Cretino adjetivo masculino
>
> Lerdo adjetivo masculino, sustantivo masculino
>
> Memo adjetivo masculino
>
> Obtuso adjetivo masculino
>
> **Zoquete** sustantivo masculino, adjetivo masculino
>
> Mentecato adjetivo masculino
>
> Zonzo adjetivo masculino
>
> Zopenco adjetivo masculino
>
> **2 En el sentido de Majadero**
>
> *Ejemplo: ¿La mía, la mía? Ya la tengo, majadero.*
>
> **Majadero** sustantivo masculino, adjetivo masculino (Torpe, molesto, **grosero**)
>
> Lelo adjetivo masculino
>
> Gilí
>
> Gilipuertas
>
> **Palabras similares a ignorante**
>
> Similar
>
> ignaro
>
> nesciente
>
> lego
>
> iletrado
>
> profano
>
> inculto
>
> rústico
>
> analfabeto
>
> asno
>
> corto
>
> rudo
>
> **necio**
>
> animal
>
> bruto
>
> bestia
>
> torpe
>
> incapaz
>
> **grosero**
>
> **zafio**
>
> berzotas
>
> cebollino
>
> adoquín
>
> ceporro
>
> tocho
>
> Opuesta
>
> **Grosero**: Descortesía, 2) Tosquedad, falta de finura, 3) **Rusticidad**, **Ignorancia**.

En este compendio de sinónimos podemos observar algunos detalles de similitud y coincidencias de otras palabras con "Ignorancia" (Ignorante). Así pues, una persona que es ignorante y no lo sabe puede ser una persona zafia, tosca, rústica o simplemente que le falta finura, sin embargo al desconocer que es poseedor de tales faltas al final acaba siendo percibido por los demás con el adjetivo "gili".

Sinónimos de Gilipollas

https://www.buscapalabra.com/sinonimos-y-antonimos.html?palabra=gilipollas&sinonimos=true#resultados

**P.D.** Otra posibilidad un poco más elegante, aunque ya no como palabra, sería utilizar una expresión que revele primeramente la ignorancia del sujeto sobre el tema en cuestión, para luego poner de relieve la otra parte de la misma, es decir, "que él no lo sabe", "no es conocedor de su ignorancia", profundizando y poniendo acento doble a esa "ignorancia". Así simplemente podríamos decir "**Fulanito esta pez en** (ejem. "*agricultura, historia, economía, matemáticas, los presupuestos, la guerra de...*") **pero él no lo sabe**.

Comment: Poner todo el diccionario no me ayuda.

Comment: No Lambie, hay que mirar las palabras sinónimas y coincidentes entre Ignorante, Gilipollas, Grosero...aunque aquí no se encuentran todas, las que están en negrita son las que he podido localizar como comunes, aunque en algunos sitios las integran y en otros no, así me he limitado hacer un resumen. Como explico en la respuesta esto soluciona solo una parte de la cuestión, pues la otra, es que la persona "no sabe que es ignorante" y por tanto, también es ajeno a lo que los demás realmente piensan de él, así, desde mi punto de vista, un "gili" une ambas cuestiones. El ser ignorante y no saberlo.

Comment: ¡Gracias Lambie!

Answer (score 0):

Quizá se asemeja a 'necio'

- 1 En su primera acepción  "Ignorante y que no sabe lo que podía o debía saber"
- 2 La segunda "Falto de inteligencia o de razón".
- 3 La tercera también suma, en cuanto a terco y porfiado.

https://dle.rae.es/necio

Answer (score 0):

**Arrogancia** y **soberbia** están relacionadas con la pregunta, no obstante la palabra que se me ocurre aplicado a uno mismo es:

### Sobrevalorado

> 1. tr. Otorgar a alguien o algo mayor valor del que realmente tiene.

Aunque la expresión más habitual es ser un **creído**.

### Creído

> Tener un sentimiento de superioridad y manifestarlo en la actitud.

<sub>*[Wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ser_un_cre%C3%ADdo)*</sub>

---

Existe algo que no es una palabra concreta sino una patología.

### Efecto Dunning-Kruger

> El efecto **Dunning-Kruger** es el sesgo cognitivo por el cual las personas con baja habilidad en una tarea sobrestiman su habilidad.

Destaco el siguiente párrafo, relacionado con la pregunta:

> Kruger y Dunning investigaron cierto número de estudios previos que tendían a sugerir que en diversas habilidades ... «La ignorancia genera confianza más frecuentemente que el conocimiento».
> • Los individuos incompetentes tienden a sobrestimar su propia habilidad.
> • Los individuos incompetentes son incapaces de reconocer la habilidad de otros.
> • Los individuos incompetentes son incapaces de reconocer su extrema insuficiencia.

<sub>*[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_Dunning-Kruger)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Quizá la palabra que buscas sea **Insipiente**

> 1. adj. Falto de sabiduría o ciencia. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Falto de juicio. U. t. c. s.